# How to not lose text selection when tapping a Spinner?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-spinner

I am working on a text editor.

I have an `EditText` widget in which the text is entered and a line below with various formatting widgets such as buttons and `Spinner`s.

The user can select text and then press a button to switch bold, italic and other formatting options on and off and this works without trouble.

However, for the `Spinner`s, by which the user can select things like color or fonts, on an Asus tablet running Android 4.1  or a Nexus 4/7/10 running 4.2.2, the text selection disappears as soon as the `Spinner` is tapped.

On a Samsung Galaxy SII, this behavior does not happen. The selection is kept throughout the interaction with the `Spinner`. (It runs Android 4.0.4 and I am not sure if the issue is Android version related or due to Samsung doing something differently).

I would like to have the behavior of Samsung on every device. How can I make sure this is the default behavior?

Comment: After testing on an emulator running 4.0.3 it seems that standard Android loses focus. So somehow Samsung has some difference in default behavior that I would like to replicate on other devices.

Comment: Running the debugger shows that through a long stack of calls, a onWindowsFocusChanged is being called, presumably to give focus to the spinner pop up dialog, and Editor onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)  is called that eventually removes the text selection. So maybe I need to set a custom action mode to avoid the issue, or save the selection in onWindowsFocusChanged before calling the super version and restore it after, but I am not sure what kind of negative side effects such an approach might create....

Comment: overriding those hooks to save and restore the selection state seems like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: I have done it and it does give me the intended behavior. I will post my code as an answer to the question once I have tested it on other devices to make sure it has no ill effect on any device I can get my hands on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a custom EditText class with the following override does the trick:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasWindowFocus) {
    boolean hadSelection = this.hasSelection();
    int start=0, end=0;
    if(hadSelection) {
        start = getSelectionStart();
        end = getSelectionEnd();
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
    if(hadSelection) {
        setSelection(start, end);
    }
}
```

I am not totally sure that in some cases it may not create some unwanted side-effects. If you use this and encounter any issue, please post a comment or publish your solution that avoids them.

Comment: It's not necessary to check hasSelection() first, so I didn't, but I can report that this works just fine on Kindle Fire HD running Amazon's system version 7.3.1.

Comment: superb, saved my life :)